# How can i remove the border between 2 textboxes that are next to each other in order to look as one

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Say I have this form of a timer:
https://gyazo.com/ffdae5829005768d53fcb625c6b971b8

The minute textbox and the second/millisecond textbox are next to eachother but there is an obvious line in between them which is the border between both seperate textbox. How do I remove this border to make it look like its just 1 seemless textbox?

Comment: If you don't want to change the `BorderStyle` as in [N0Alias answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499181/how-can-i-remove-the-border-between-2-textboxes-that-are-next-to-each-other-in-o/46499355#46499355) below, you can keep the `BorderStyle` as default if you want it on the sides that are not touching, and where the `TextBoxes` are touching you can put above the border a white empty label, set the `AutoSize` to `False` and resize it to cover the border where the 2 `TextBoxes` are touching.

Comment: Why not using one textbox for displaying minutes and seconds

Answer (score 1):

While viewing the form in designer mode you can right click one of the textboxes and select Properties.  This should open a pane that will permit you to change the BorderStyle property to None.  Do this for both textboxes and it will appear seamless.

[image: BorderStyle Property]

Answer (score 0):

You can do what [NoAlias did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499181/how-can-i-remove-the-border-between-2-textboxes-that-are-next-to-each-other-in-o/46499355#46499355) but this will not show any border at all. I think you want to make it look like a single textbox right?

I have three other suggestions:

> 1. Use a single textbox to show Minute and Second/Millisecond.
> 2. Use a label. Set it's background color to the same as textbox background and put it between those textboxes. This will make it look
>      like it's a single box too.
> 3. Do what [NoAlias did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46499181/how-can-i-remove-the-border-between-2-textboxes-that-are-next-to-each-other-in-o/46499355#46499355), and add a `RectangleShape` around the two textboxes to make it look like a textbox. You can find it in the toolbox under the heading `Visual Basic PowerPacks`.